# java.lang.InternalError Thread starting during runtime shutdown

Tags: android, android-asynctask, background-process

We are not able to get the exact cause of this exception. Does anybody have an idea, why this exception occurs in android application? Thanks in advance.

Here is the full stack trace of Exception :

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.InternalError: Thread starting during runtime shutdown
       at java.lang.Thread.nativeCreate(Thread.java)
       at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:1063)
       at org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.AbstractConnPool.enableConnectionGC(AbstractConnPool.java:145)
       at org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ThreadSafeClientConnManager.createConnectionPool(ThreadSafeClientConnManager.java:125)
       at org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ThreadSafeClientConnManager.<init>(ThreadSafeClientConnManager.java:103)
       at org.acra.util.HttpRequest.getHttpClient(HttpRequest.java:214)
       at org.acra.util.HttpRequest.send(HttpRequest.java:141)
       at org.acra.sender.HttpSender.send(HttpSender.java:225)
       at org.acra.SendWorker.sendCrashReport(SendWorker.java:179)
       at org.acra.SendWorker.checkAndSendReports(SendWorker.java:141)
       at org.acra.SendWorker.run(SendWorker.java:77)
```

Comment: Write full callstack trace.

Comment: It's not ANR. The application is getting crashed on a specific screen.

Comment: https://github.com/ACRA/acra/issues/196

Answer (score -2):

```
void Thread::CreateNativeThread(JNIEnv* env, jobject java_peer, size_t stack_size, bool is_daemon) {
  CHECK(java_peer != nullptr);
  Thread* self = static_cast<JNIEnvExt*>(env)->self;

  if (VLOG_IS_ON(threads)) {
    ScopedObjectAccess soa(env);

    ArtField* f = soa.DecodeField(WellKnownClasses::java_lang_Thread_name);
    mirror::String* java_name = reinterpret_cast<mirror::String*>(f->GetObject(
        soa.Decode<mirror::Object*>(java_peer)));
    std::string thread_name;
    if (java_name != nullptr) {
      thread_name = java_name->ToModifiedUtf8();
    } else {
      thread_name = "(Unnamed)";
    }

    VLOG(threads) << "Creating native thread for " << thread_name;
    self->Dump(LOG(INFO));
  }

  Runtime* runtime = Runtime::Current();

  // Atomically start the birth of the thread ensuring the runtime isn't shutting down.
  bool thread_start_during_shutdown = false;
  {
    MutexLock mu(self, *Locks::runtime_shutdown_lock_);
    if (runtime->IsShuttingDownLocked()) {
      thread_start_during_shutdown = true;
    } else {
      runtime->StartThreadBirth();
    }
  }
  if (thread_start_during_shutdown) {//At there!!!
    ScopedLocalRef<jclass> error_class(env, env->FindClass("java/lang/InternalError"));
    env->ThrowNew(error_class.get(), "Thread starting during runtime shutdown");
    return;
  }

  Thread* child_thread = new Thread(is_daemon);
  // Use global JNI ref to hold peer live while child thread starts.
  child_thread->tlsPtr_.jpeer = env->NewGlobalRef(java_peer);
  stack_size = FixStackSize(stack_size);

  // Thread.start is synchronized, so we know that nativePeer is 0, and know that we're not racing to
  // assign it.
  env->SetLongField(java_peer, WellKnownClasses::java_lang_Thread_nativePeer,
                    reinterpret_cast<jlong>(child_thread));

  // Try to allocate a JNIEnvExt for the thread. We do this here as we might be out of memory and
  // do not have a good way to report this on the child's side.
  std::unique_ptr<JNIEnvExt> child_jni_env_ext(
      JNIEnvExt::Create(child_thread, Runtime::Current()->GetJavaVM()));

  int pthread_create_result = 0;
  if (child_jni_env_ext.get() != nullptr) {
    pthread_t new_pthread;
    pthread_attr_t attr;
    child_thread->tlsPtr_.tmp_jni_env = child_jni_env_ext.get();
    CHECK_PTHREAD_CALL(pthread_attr_init, (&attr), "new thread");
    CHECK_PTHREAD_CALL(pthread_attr_setdetachstate, (&attr, PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED),
                       "PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED");
    CHECK_PTHREAD_CALL(pthread_attr_setstacksize, (&attr, stack_size), stack_size);
    pthread_create_result = pthread_create(&new_pthread,
                                           &attr,
                                           Thread::CreateCallback,
                                           child_thread);
    CHECK_PTHREAD_CALL(pthread_attr_destroy, (&attr), "new thread");

    if (pthread_create_result == 0) {
      // pthread_create started the new thread. The child is now responsible for managing the
      // JNIEnvExt we created.
      // Note: we can't check for tmp_jni_env == nullptr, as that would require synchronization
      //       between the threads.
      child_jni_env_ext.release();
      return;
    }
  }

  // Either JNIEnvExt::Create or pthread_create(3) failed, so clean up.
  {
    MutexLock mu(self, *Locks::runtime_shutdown_lock_);
    runtime->EndThreadBirth();
  }
  // Manually delete the global reference since Thread::Init will not have been run.
  env->DeleteGlobalRef(child_thread->tlsPtr_.jpeer);
  child_thread->tlsPtr_.jpeer = nullptr;
  delete child_thread;
  child_thread = nullptr;
  // TODO: remove from thread group?
  env->SetLongField(java_peer, WellKnownClasses::java_lang_Thread_nativePeer, 0);
  {
    std::string msg(child_jni_env_ext.get() == nullptr ?
        "Could not allocate JNI Env" :
        StringPrintf("pthread_create (%s stack) failed: %s",
                                 PrettySize(stack_size).c_str(), strerror(pthread_create_result)));
    ScopedObjectAccess soa(env);
    soa.Self()->ThrowOutOfMemoryError(msg.c_str());
  }
}
```

Comment: Don't you think an explanation would have been better